# How to set up object transformations,properties?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL, and doing homework from online lessons. My first task was to fill skillet with a code for: rotate, scale, translate, perspective, move left/right, up/down. I did it, but met a problem with next task: setting up transformations. Could you show me an example or some links how to do it? 
Any help would appreciate.

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < numobjects ; i++) {
    object* obj = &(objects[i]); 

    // Set up the object transformations 
    // And pass in the appropriate material properties
    // Again glUniform() related functions will be useful

    // Actually draw the object
    // We provide the actual glut drawing functions for you.  
    // Remember that obj->type is notation for accessing struct fields


    if (obj->type == cube) {
      glutSolidCube(obj->size); 
    }
    else if (obj->type == sphere) {
      const int tessel = 20; 
      glutSolidSphere(obj->size, tessel, tessel); 
    }
    else if (obj->type == teapot) {
      glutSolidTeapot(obj->size); 
    }

  }
```

---

```
const int maxobjects = 10 ; 
EXTERN int numobjects ; 
EXTERN struct object {
  shape type ; 
  GLfloat size ;
  GLfloat ambient[4] ; 
  GLfloat diffuse[4] ; 
  GLfloat specular[4] ;
  GLfloat emission[4] ; 
  GLfloat shininess ;
  mat4 transform ; 

} objects[maxobjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

Transformations in modern OpenGL are done by using uniform matrices in the shader. Basically, you will have to query the uniform location of the transformation variable ([glGetUniformLocation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml)) and then pass the `obj->transform` member to this location by using [glUniformMatrix4fv](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml).

For the material parameters the workflow is basically the same, but with a different glUniform* call that fits the type.